# SSDT Parameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to use SSDT to deploy a report that will allow for the input of 2 parameters that I can use for the start and the end of a log file. My parameters are declared as DateTime under the Parameters dropdown under Report Data. The Dataset has the Parameters included in it's properties as well. This is my SQL statement and error.

```
[Declare] @StartTime DateTime 
[Declare] @EndTime Datetime 
SELECT RecordID, AnalysisID, HeatName, NewHeatName, AnalysisTime, SampleType, Grade, NewGrade, ProductID, RecordChangeTime, ChangesMade, LoggedUser
FROM Chemistry_Log
WHERE (RecordChangeTime >= @ StartTime) AND (RecordChangeTime <= @ EndTime)
```

The following errors were encountered while parsing the contents of the SQL pane:

Unable to parse query text.

I'm not sure where to go from here, because that isn't very informative of an error message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already added the parameters to the report you don't need to declare them again when defining the query.

Also, maybe it's a typo, but you should remove the spaces in `@ StartTime` and `@ EndTime`

So just something like:

```
SELECT RecordID, AnalysisID, HeatName, NewHeatName, AnalysisTime, SampleType, Grade, NewGrade, ProductID, RecordChangeTime, ChangesMade, LoggedUser
FROM Chemistry_Log
WHERE (RecordChangeTime >= @StartTime) AND (RecordChangeTime <= @EndTime)
```

Comment: As of now though, when I take out the declaration statement, it tells me that I need to declare my variables. I have also changed the WHERE statement to "WHERE (RecordChangeTime BETWEEN (@StartDate) AND (@EndDate))" but I don't think it makes a difference. Also, the spaces aren't there when I run the query, but when I open it back up to edit it, they appear..